# Replicate Amazon-ec2 development environment on local machine

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, virtual-machines, lamp

I have a development vm on amazon ec2 with with a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64bit) instance and LAMP stack. I would like to replicate that locally on my MBP. Is that possible? How would I go about doing that? Would I need something like VirturalBox running Ubuntu and use rsync?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it, but I don't see any reason why running [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/get.html) on the EC2 machine wouldn't work.  Just pretend it's a physical machine.  I suspect that the EC2 Linux is close enough to RedHat for it even to do its fancy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

General steps are: create new virtual machine on local computer, boot it with live CD (System Rescue CD for example), create and mount partitions, rsync content of original machine to new machine, install boot loader, reboot new virtual machine.
You can find detailed instructions in Google. Examples: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/komputes/HowToCloneFilesystem, http://carlton.oriley.net/drupal/node/15, http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9942?page=0,0.